# Installation of libavcodec-extra or libmp3lame fails

Tags: apt, software-installation, libav, lame

I'm trying to install ffmpeg on my dedicated server running on ubuntu 10.04. I want to convert flv-videos to mp3 sound files.
As I found out, I have to install libavcodec-extra-52. When I use

> sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-52

it says that I don't have libfaac0 (>= 1.26) and libmp3lame0 and that they aren't installable. Using

> sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0

it says that the package isn't available at any source. Do I need some special repository to be able to download those codecs? Right at the moment, I have only three sources for packages in /etc/apt/sources.list which are predefined and hosted by my provider.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && apt-cache search libavcodec-extra` what is the result of this command? Also try this combo to try to fix some apt issues `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: The first command gives a list of several repositories and "OK" in front of each. Then it says `winff - graphical video and audio batch converter using ffmpeg
libavcodec-extra-52 - ffmpeg codec library`. The second command repaired many packages, but didn't change anything.

Comment: 10.04 is EOL and off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Follow [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1117283) and you should be fine.

Ubuntu, or in better terms, the package `libavcodec-extra-52`, does not support the libraries that you must have installed in order to use ffmpeg for what you want to do. You can find explanations and howtos at that linked guide.

Comment: Thanks, I already found that link before and tried solution B. That's where I found out that I need libavcodec-extra-52. I just tried solution A and successfully compiled LAME and ffmpeg. BUT I still don't have libmp3lame, so I can't rip a mp3-file from a flv-file because I don't have the codec. How can I build a libmp3lame out of the already installed LAME?

Comment: I just noticed that there is a folder libmp3lame in the LAME sources folder. But there is no configure-file and make doens't do anything.

Comment: did you have `libmp3lame0` installed? `sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0` if you have to find a package use `apt-cache search package`, if you are looking for what libraries are missing for a specific executable, just use `ldd $(which ffmpeg)`

Comment: Okay, the problem is solved, i forgot to use --enable-libmp3lame while configuring ffmpeg. Now everything works fine.